# Excel 2010 SUMIFS criteria array in a reference cell is not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate hours using an array of values (asset class types). When I put the array in the formula directly it works correctly.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($H:$H,$G:$G,A$1,$F:$F,{"CS","CD","TA"}))
```

However, when I put the array in an external cell and reference it in the formula I get 0. In this example D2 is `{"CS","CD","TA"}`

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($H:$H,$G:$G,A$1,$F:$F,D2))
```

How can I get the SUMIFS formula to recognize D2 as an array and process it correctly? I need to extrapolate this to a much larger dataset that will be updated on a somewhat regular basis, so I would rather not hard-code the asset class arrays.

Spreadsheet example:

[image: Spreadsheet example]

[Link to file on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/15sv9m28u9uudv7/SUMIFS%20Fault%20Finding.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Im know of no way to accomplish what you are attempting. The text string you've placed in C3 is not an actual array.

You could try an old fashioned SUM(IF(... array formula.

```
=SUM(IF(G2:G21=C2, IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(F2:F21, D3)), H2:H21)))
```

Finalize this in the cell with ctrl+shift+enter, not just enter.

The value in D3 could be written as simple as `CS, CD, TA`.